# How is $\int_0^1 \ln(\frac{1}{1-x})dx=1$ using series expansion?

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms

How is

$$\int_0^1 \ln \left(\frac{1}{1-x} \right) dx=1$$

using series expansion?

This is simple if one integrates it directly by first noting that the integrand is same as $-\ln(1-x)$, which can be seen [here](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/-%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%20%5Cln%5Cleft(1-x%5Cright)). The expansion is

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^j}{j}$$

but integrating this, I don't see how it could produce $1$?

Comment: $\frac{1}{j(j+1)} = \frac{1}{j} - \frac{1}{j+1}$

Comment: @MichaelBiro Yes, but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}=\infty$

Comment: @MichaelBiro Also, the series you give has value $1$, but how does this tell anything about series $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you integrate, you get
$$\int_0^1\left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{x^j}j\right)\,dx
=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\int_0^1\frac{x^j}j\,dx=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac1{j(j+1)}
=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\left(\frac1j-\frac1{j+1}\right)$$
which is the classic telescoping sum
$$\left(1-\frac12\right)+\left(\frac12-\frac13\right)
+\left(\frac13-\frac14\right)+\cdots$$
etc.